# Cómo el usuario encargado agregar al menos 5 películas para después mostrarlas por pantalla

Tags: python, python-3.9

Tengo un problema al tratar de recuperar la información que digito me devuelve lo no esperado en mi objeto película
Hice un bucle while para ver si me podría retornar la información de las películas pero he olvidado como

```
class Pelicula():
    def __init__(self, titulo, director, genero, duracion):
        self.titulo = titulo
        self.director = director
        self.genero = genero
        self.duracion = duracion


    def agregar_titulo(self, titulo):
        self.titulo = titulo
        return self.titulo

    def agregar_director(self, director):
        self.director = director
        return self.director

    def agregar_genero(self, genero):
        self.genero = genero
        return self.genero

    def agregar_duracion(self, duracion):
        self.duracion = duracion
        return self.duracion

    def mostrar_pelicula(self,mostrar):
        self.mostrar = mostrar
        return self.mostrar

while True:
    print("""
    1. Agregar pelicula
    2. Mostrar pelicula
    3. Salir""")

    opcion = input("Ingrese una opcion: ")

    if opcion == "1":
        titulo = input("Ingrese el titulo de la pelicula: ")
        director = input("Ingrese el director de la pelicula: ")
        genero = input("Ingrese el género de la pelicula: ")
        duracion = input("Ingrese la duración de la pelicula: ")
        pelicula = Pelicula(titulo, director, genero, duracion)
        print(pelicula.mostrar_pelicula(pelicula))

        break
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Primero

comencemos con los requerimientos

1. Necesitas una forma de ingresar 5 películas
2. Cada película contiene título, director, género y duración
3. Necesitas una forma de presentar todas las películas  creada en pantalla.

## Segundo,

sobre tu código, veo dos errores:

- `print(pelicula.mostrar_pelicula(pelicula))` En este caso python te devuelve algo como `<__main__.Pelicula object at 0x0000022255C3BFD0>` simplemente porque estas preguntando por el objeto, y no se a definido una representación del objeto. Es decir python te responde, “ si el objeto existe y esta en esta dirección” pero no te dice que contiene. Una solución es usar dunder methods, en este caso `__repr__`.

Puedes sobre escribir el método `__repr__` para que te de una descripción del objeto, o en otras palabras puedes definir la representación del objeto. Ejemplo:

```py
class Pelicula():
    def __init__(self, titulo, director, genero, duración):
        ...

    def agregar_titulo(self, titulo):
        ...

    def agregar_director(self, director):
        ...

    def agregar_genero(self, genero):
        ...

    def agregar_duracion(self, duracion):
        ...

    def __repr__(self):
        msg = f"Titulo: {self.titulo}\n"
        msg += f"Director: {self.director}\n"
        msg += f"Genero: {self.genero}\n"
        msg += f"Duracion: {self.duracion}\n"
        return msg
```

- `break` El break al final del bucle `if`. le estas diciedo al programa que se salga del `while`, por lo que luego de ejecutar el print el programa se saldra del `while`.

Puedes usar `continue`, `else` y `break`

```py
while True:
    print("""
    1. Agregar pelicula
    2. Mostrar pelicula
    3. Salir""")
    opcion = input("Ingrese una opcion: ")

    if opcion == "1":
        ...

        continue
    else:
        break
```

De esta manera una vez se imprima la el objeto película, se pasara a correr el siguiente bucle, o saltar a la siguiente iteración, esa es la tarea de `continue`.
luego para asegurarse que el bucle va a tener una salida puedes usar `else` y `break` de esta maneras si el usuario elige una opción diferente a `1` el programa se termina.

## Tercero

Este es un ejemplo de como se veria un codigo similar al que quieres

1. Una clase `Pelicula` que abstrae película, es decir va a representar una sola película
2. La clase `Pelicula` puede ser una `dataclass` o una clase normal sin métodos.
3. Puedes guardar las películas en una base de datos, o en un arreglo de objetos.
4. Se tendrá una segunda clase que será usada para consultar las películas existentes, esta clase se puede llamar `Consultor` y tendrá solo un método
5. El método de la clase `Consultor` simplemente desplegara las películas guardadas en el arreglo.

```py
class Pelicula():
    def __init__(self, titulo, director, genero, duración):
        self.titulo = titulo
        self.director = director
        self.genero = genero
        self.duracion = duracion


    def agregar_titulo(self, titulo):
        self.titulo = titulo
        return self.titulo

    def agregar_director(self, director):
        self.director = director
        return self.director

    def agregar_genero(self, genero):
        self.genero = genero
        return self.genero

    def agregar_duracion(self, duracion):
        self.duracion = duracion
        return self.duracion

    def __repr__(self):
        msg = f"=====================\n"
        msg += f"Titulo: {self.titulo}\n"
        msg += f"Director: {self.director}\n"
        msg += f"Genero: {self.genero}\n"
        msg += f"Duracion: {self.duracion}\n"
        return msg



class Consultor:

    def mostrar_peliculas(self, repisa):
        for pelicula in repisa:
            print(pelicula)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    # guarda los objetos pelicula
    repisa_de_peliculars = list()

    while True:
        print(f"1. Agregar pelicula\n2. Mostrar pelicula\n3. Salir")

        opt = input("Ingrese una opcion: ")

        if opt in "1":
            titulo = input("Ingrese el titulo de la pelicula: ")
            director = input("Ingrese el director de la pelicula: ")
            genero = input("Ingrese el género de la pelicula: ")
            duracion = input("Ingrese la duración de la pelicula: ")
            pelicula = Pelicula(titulo, director, genero, duracion)
            repisa_de_peliculars.append(pelicula)
            continue

        else:
            break

    c = Consultor()
    c.mostrar_peliculas(repisa_de_peliculars)
```

Trata de no copiar el código, trata de entender por qué se hizo de dicha manera.
Yo implementaría el código de una manera diferente pero lo hice de esta manera ya que es similar al que tú ya hiciste.

### Un consejo sobre clases

Hay dos tipos de clases:

1. Clases que representan información or datos
2. Clases que tienen acciones o que actúan de ciertas maneras.

Para este caso la clase película podría ser del primer tipo, por lo que podrías usar `dataclases`, python en las últimas versiones soporta esta estructura de datos.

La segunda clase `Consultor` estará dedicada simplemente a realizar acciones, es decir del segundo tipo, por ejemplo crear películas, eliminar películas y mostrar películas.

De esta maneras si en algún momento decides modificar la información de las películas, por ejemplo agregar información sobre los actores, solo debes modificar la clase película  y no como se obtiene o crea. Con el tiempo te darás cuenta que pensar de esta maneras simplificara tu código y lo hará mas fácil de actualizar

Comment: En el `def __init__(self,etc....` ha quedado acentuado con tilde **duración** cuando en el resto de código no lleva tilde.